# Find the probability of random line passing through two circles given that it passes through the first.

Tags: probability, geometry, circles, tangent-line

Given two circles C​1​ and C2​​ in a plane with radius r1 = 4​​, r2 = 5 respectively and the distance between centers of C1 ​​and C​2 is 15, find the probability that a randomly chosen line​​ will cross both circles given that the chosen line crosses C1.

I tried to relate it to the common tangents but couldn't get too far.

Comment: the prior distribution of this parameter is "uniform over the reals"

Comment: "uniform over the reals": there are two problems with this definition. (1) The uniform distribution over the reals is not defined (in the case of standard Kolmogorov theory). (2) At least I don't understand how a real would determine a line.

Comment: The probability space which is being meant here is the angle with X-axis, and value of y at x = 0

Comment: The problematic variable is the katter one...